# Installed PySide but can't import it: "no module named PySide"

Tags: python, pyside

I'm new to Python.  I have both Python 2.7 and Python 3 installed.  I just tried installing PySide via Homebrew and got this message:

> PySide package successfully installed in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PySide...

Both versions of Python and the newly installed PySide are all stored in 
`/usr/local/Cellar/`.

This issue is that when I'm in either Python 2.7 or Python 3 and try to import PySide or run a test program that includes PySide, I get the message: "no module named PySide".

This is on OS X 10.9.3

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I've searched far and wide and tried reinstalling a few times with the same results.

The full `sys.path` output:

When I run while in Python 3:

```
>>> print(sys.path)
['', '/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python34.zip', '/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4', '/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/plat-darwin', '/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages']
```

When I run while in Python 2:

```
>>> print sys.path
['', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/distribute-0.6.49-py2.7.egg', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg-info']
```

Comment: What does `which python` output?

Comment: Are you using the System Python (*that OS X ships with*)?

Comment: $ which python
/usr/bin/python

Comment: No I installed the latest version of Python myself - thanks

Comment: sys.path for when I'm in Python 2.7 is: >>> import sys
>>> print sys.path
['', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/distribute-0.6.49-py2.7.egg', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip', .....

Comment: `/usr/bin/python` is the default OS X python.

Comment: Try using `python2` or `python3` to run your code.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara - ok I'm new to this, but it doesn't work when I try to use python2 or python3 to run the code.  In both cases it doesn't seem to recognize that I downloaded PySide in /usr/local/Cellar/.  It gives me a "no module" return. Thanks

Comment: Did you install Python via Homebrew or the python.org installer packages? If the later, you might want to use Homebrew to install Python.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PySide was installed to `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages`, but Python isn’t looking there; it’s looking in `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages`. Additionally, `which python` gave `/usr/bin/python` rather than `/usr/local/bin/python`, so you’re using the system Python.

The path forward depends on whether you want to use the system Python or Homebrew Python:

- **System Python:** You’ll need to either add `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages` to your `sys.path` (possibly in `/Library/Python/2.7/site.py`) or move `PySide` to `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages`.
- **Homebrew Python:** You’ll need to add `/usr/local/bin` to your `PATH`, probably in `~/.bashrc`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this, I'd like to use homebrew python, but not 100% sure how to implement your advice of adding /user/local/bin to my PATH.  If you are also able to advise on this, that would be awesome.

Comment: @jessminda: If you edit the `.bashrc` file in your home directory, you can add a line like `export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"`. Then when you restart Terminal, when you type `python`, it should first look for `/usr/local/bin/python`, and if that’s there, `/usr/bin/python` will never get involved.

Comment: @jessminda: And if that doesn’t work you may need to add `. ~/.bashrc` to your `.bash_login` file. But that might not be necessary.

Comment: Thanks once again @icktoofay! I think I managed it with this line: export PATH=/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH.  Now the line $ which python returns:  /usr/local/bin/python.  The import PySide function is working as well

Comment: How can I solve this problem in Windows? Can you please share??

Answer (score 1):

**For windows users** the case is almost same,this kind of error is encountered when you have multiple python interpreters are installed , and you have installed PySide2 in one installation and trying to run your code using other installation.
Create a virtual environment for your project and install all modules in that virtual environment. It'll avoid the issue.
Hope it work:)